# Merge svn branch to new git branch

Tags: git, svn, version-control, merge

We are moving from a svn repository to a git repository

Although the svn trunk was migrated, the branches were not(svn server is maintained by a different team).

So I am left with a local copy of svn branch which is almost 6 months older than the current git repository.

If you want to ask why 6 months, it was a huge feature so 2 months went into development and rest 4 months were wasted because the feature could not be released due to some blockers.

How can I now merge my local svn branch which has these bunch of changes on 6 months old code to a git branch ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could

- [git-svn that SVN repo into a git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2244252/6309)
- add that new git repo as a remote of your existing git repo [and fetch it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14383288/6309)

  ```
  cd /path/to/existing/repo
  git remote add gitsvn /path/to/gitsvn/repo
  git fetch gitsvn
  ```
- create a new branch in your current Git repo at a point you estimate that 6 month effort might have started
- cherry-pick the fetched commit onto that new branch
- finally, merge that new Git branch in your master branch

Comment: Well, I will try this. But are there any chances of loss of code ?

Comment: @adirohan no, the code will be there: only the merge should be done carefully in order to properly integrate the two histories.

Comment: "add that new git repo as a remote of your existing git repo", I am new to git. How do I do this ?

Comment: @adirohan I have added the commands, but don't forget to click on the links present in said answer: they do add to the explanations.

Comment: Ok, I have reached till the cherry pick point. I use source tree; I dont see any remotes named gitsvn in there or in my local branches. How do I cherry pick ?

Comment: @adirohan gitsvn is just an example, as a name for your remote (in `git remote add gitsvn /path/to/your/git/repo/imported/from/svn`). Check first that you have two remotes in your current repo (in command line: `git remote -v`) then go back to your GUI (here SourceTree) and check you automatically refresh those metadata: see https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/refreshing-repository-according-to-file-changes-and-remote-changes-on-sourcetree-785323792.html

Comment: What if I do this: After adding a new remote to gitsvn, checkout as local branch then push it to my origin remote. I can then merge it to my origin master ?

Comment: @adirohan you could, but  if you already pushed to origin/master, you wouldn't need to merge to origin/master

Comment: I meant push as a new branch to my origin not directly to master. Will this have any consequences to my history ?

Comment: No, once you have imported from SVN, you can what you want with your Git repo.